# Neo4j with docker: Giving error when I try to start an instance of the neo4j image

Tags: neo4j, docker

I'm new to using docker and trying to pull and run a couple of neo4j images which fail giving an error something like this:

2015/06/18 17:16:26 Error response from daemon: Cannot start container : /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/ is not within /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/

The error persists with different images : 
seenickcode/neo4j-docker-community, 
kbastani/docker-neo4j etc.

Can someone help me out here?

Also, when I try to build a simple neo4j image using a Dockerfile, the time it takes to start the neo4j server is very long. Is this normal?

Thanks a lot in advance. :)

Comment: how do you start the container?

Comment: docker run -d --name neo4j --privileged -p 127.0.0.1:7474:7474 -p 127.0.0.1:1337:1337 seenickcode/neo4j-community

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to mount the data volume in both cases, unfortunately Nicks doesn't have any docs but Kenny's has:

```
docker run -d -p 7474:7474 -v /Users/<user>/path/to/neo4j/data:/opt/data --name graphdb kbastani/docker-neo4j
```

Answer (score 0):

use the official neo4j image.

Try this command :-

```
docker run --name neo4j --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 -v c:/My-Folder/neo4j/data:/data -v c:/My-Folder/neo4j/logs:/logs -v c:/My-Folder/neo4j/Csv-Data:/import -v c:/My-Folder/neo4j/configuration:/conf -v c:/My-Folder/neo4j/plugins:/plugins neo4j
```

This will mount the volume for database, log files, your CSV data files, neo4j config file(this would overwrite the config file) and the plugins folder (if you wish to use APOC)